# How is that servlet-name and servlet-class differs?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I followed a servlet tutorial, created a servlet(`HelloServlet`) in a java file named `HelloServlet.java`.Compiled the .java file to `HelloServet.class`. My questions
1) Is the servlet's name is same with servlet file(name for the compiled java file) or should be different?

This is because on the example I followed, he set the servlet-name different from the `servlet-class`, in `web.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

servlet-name is not related to servlet class name. it is used to link the servlet class  with the servlet mapping. In the below example i have used servlet-name XXX while declaring a servlet and then mapped it with the test url by giving the same servlet-name in the mapping file.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>XXX</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>className</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>XXX</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```